# How do I provide source-level debugging for a language like VS does for TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, source-maps

I understand the concept of using source maps with JavaScript to make debugging easier with minified scripts, etc.  What I don't get is how source-level debugging works like it does for TypeScript in Visual Studio (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2012/11/15/announcing-typescript-0-8-1.aspx).

For example, if I create my own language that compiles/translates to JavaScript, how do I interface with browsers to provide this kind of source-level debugging?  Is there a standard protocol for this?  How does Visual Studio do it?

**Update**

To clarify even more, let's say I invent a language called Caffeinated Beverage Script that compiles to JavaScript.  I build an IDE for my language and I want to be able to set breakpoints, step through code, inspect variables, etc. in my IDE while the JavaScript runs in a browser.  How do I get my IDE to communicate with the browser on this level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider WebKit's remote debugging API:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.0/index

I believe that's what Sublime Web Inspector uses.

https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector

Comment: I found this exact thing yesterday as well.  I don't really mind if this is WebKit/Chrome-specific, since it's free and available on all the platforms I care about.  It turns out that Visual Studio TypeScript debugging is only supported in Internet Explorer, so I'm guessing it uses some IE-specific protocol or interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly a bad answer, but I figure its better than nothing. If I were in your shoes, here is what I would do:

Now its obviously possible to communicate from the browser to the IDE using some kind of plugin, but I don't like that for at least 2 reasons: I don't enjoy coding in strongly-typed languages, and any code I produce will be inherently browser-specific. Although its not the lightest weight solution, XHR in blocking mode can get the job done.

The IDE would host a http server that sends the [CORS header](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-cors). The compiled source would contain something like this:

```
var ___, __INTERRUPT_SIGNAL = {};

(function() {
  var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  oXhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/debugging_port', false); // Force XHR to work synchronously

  ___ = function(nLineNumber) {
    var sState = 'line_number='+nLineNumber;

    for(var nOffset = 0; nOffset < arguments.length; nOffset++) sState += '&i=' + escape(arguments[nOffset]);

    oXhr.send(sState);

    if(oXhr.status !== 200) return ___.apply(this, arguments); 
    var sCommand = oXhr.responseText;

    if(sCommand === 'step_into') {
      return;  
    }else if(sCommand === 'step_out') {
      throw __INTERRUPT_SIGNAL;
    }else{
      return ___.apply(this, arguments);
    }   
  };
})();
```

Now when the Caffeinated Beverage Script compiler compiles the source, it should place calls to the *_* function at every line break of the source. For example,

```
int nCheese = 0;
char cLetter = 'Q';
customClass productZeroQ = nCheese * cLetter;
```

might compile to something like

```
var $0xA1, $0xA2, $0xA3;
___(9, $0xA1, $0xA2, $0xA3);
$0xA1 = 0;
___(10, $0xA1, $0xA2, $0xA3);
$0xA2 = 'Q';
___(11, $0xA1, $0xA2, $0xA3);
try {
  $0xA3 = $0x34.$0x21($0xA1, $0xA2);
}catch(oSignal){
  if(oSignal !== ___INTERRUPT_SIGNAL) throw oSignal;
}
```

XHR will block execution while the IDE decides to whether to step_out or step_forward. This could be extended to include the stack tracing, but I don't feel like writing a novel.

I know it's ugly, but I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Interesting approach.  However, I'm not sure I want to put this kind of debugging code in the compiled output if I can avoid it.  Still a cool idea, though.

Comment: I should have clarified; it would probably be best to have a "debug" setting on the compiler. In production statements like that could easily double the size of the compiled output.

Comment: No worries; I assumed that this was intended for a debug configuration.