# Debugging transpiled javascript-- how does that work?

Tags: javascript, debugging, coffeescript

There are lots of ways to transpile other variants (Typescript, coffeescript, ES6-->ES5) to 'common', ES5 javascript.  But the resulting script is often unreadable to humans and impossible to debug in a browser as-is.

My understanding is that source maps aid in the process, but I'm not sure how they do their thing.  At a high level, how does it work, debugging transpiled javascript in IE/FireFox/Chrome?  Do they follow a similar convention or have their own way(s) of handling the mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I provide source-level debugging for a language like VS does for TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820126/how-do-i-provide-source-level-debugging-for-a-language-like-vs-does-for-typescri)